# Dynamic entity framework linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create a method that will generate EF Core linq queries dynamically which I intend to use on a generic page in my app.

So far I have this...

```
    public static IQueryable<object> LoadGridData(this DbContext context, GridLoadParameters parameters)
{
  List<string> includes = new List<string>();
  foreach (string str in parameters.Columns)
  {
    string path = str.StripLastElement('.');
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && !includes.Contains(path))
      includes.Add(path);
  }
  includes = includes.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();

  IQueryable<object> linq = ((IQueryable)context.PropertyByName(parameters.Table.Pluralize())).OfType<object>();

  foreach (string path in includes)
    linq = linq.Include(path);

  foreach (OrderColumn order in parameters.Order)
    if (order.Direction == OrderDirection.Ascending)
      linq = ((IQueryable)linq).Cast<object>().OrderBy(x => x.PropertyByName(order.ColumnPath));
    else
      linq = ((IQueryable)linq).Cast<object>().OrderByDescending(x => x.PropertyByName(order.ColumnPath));

  linq = linq.Skip(parameters.ItemsToSkip).Take(parameters.ItemsToTake)
    .Select(CreateLambdaObjectArraySelect<object>(parameters.Columns));
  return linq;
}
```

The problem I have is with the Include(path) line.  To keep the query dynamic I have had to cast the result to type 'object'.  This is fine when accessing the properties because I have an extension method 'PropertyByName' which uses reflection to retrieve the value.

However, the Include(path) line needs to understand the entity type in order to work and as all the results have been cast to object it fails with the error 'The Include operation 'Include("Period")' is not supported. 'Period' must be a navigation property defined on an entity type.'

I have considered using a dynamic linq library but I really wanted to see if I could solve the problem without it first.  After all, if the library can do it, there must be a way!

Comment: Instead of 'object' why not use a generic type paramter? I'm assuming you would know this when calling LoadGridData()...

Comment: *This is fine when accessing the properties* No, it's not fine. Although EF Core supports that (which cannot be said for EF6), it leads to so called client evaluation rather that translation to SQL. You really need to take reflection and custom methods off and build expressions. So there is a way, but it's not easy, so dynamic linq library will help a lot.

Comment: Cal279 - I don't know the type at that point.  I only know the type at runtime.

Comment: Ivan Stoev - can you explain more?  One thing that I didn't mention is that everything works until I try to use include statements.

Comment: @Slade It works by retrieving the whole tabl in memory and performing the ordering and pagination (`Skip` and `Take`) there. Which basically kills the whole idea of pagination.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev OK, I get it.  I'm working towards a solution that takes that into account and actually uses Cal279's advice too after I worked out a way I could implement it in a generic way